# Which weapon is first in the rankings?

Tags: angel-n-devil

In *Angel 'N' Devil*, we know that Excalibur and Iliad's Twin Stars are third in the weapons ranking, and that Hades's Hooked Swords or whatever is second. But do we ever find out what is first?

Since the weapon ranking seems to be basically correlated with the destructive power of the user, I'd imagine the wielder would probably have a destructive power of more than Kou Chi's 11,000.

I suppose Chi An's Demon Axe might be an obvious candidate, but since it only works against demons and Chi An doesn't have a destructive power, I am not sure how that would work.

What weapon is first in the rankings?

Comment: Is it '***over 9000!***'?